# Browser compatibility issue for IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

While fixing some browser compatibility issue I faced a really confusing problem like the application is running well in Firefox 28,29 etc, chrome and IE 9. But when I try to make it run in IE 8 it is taking some property like : sizzle-1398717162242="[object Object]".The alignment is also breaking. Is this because of that extra added property? Please help.

Comment: The sizzle based property is typically related to jQuery adding a reference for speedy future lookups.  99.99% of the time this is totally fine and won't cause any issues.  If you can post some of your code we can see better what the root cause is.

Comment: It is a normal html page. Yes I used jquery there. There is a header..where i used jquery to show / hide login div. There is a menu using html and css. Then I used a plugin for sliding image gallery. But not getting what is the root cause of this problem.

Comment: Are you using jQuery version 2.0 or higher? If so that is the reason... jQuery 2.x only supports IE9+   If this isn't the issue, please provide some code or a URL that we can look at.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included very much information on what is actually breaking except the alignment but if you are using some new tags or features you can go to http://caniuse.com and check what browsers and versions they are supported in.

Comment: this might be better fitted for a comment instead of an answer `:)`